# Among the first ones to be laid off temporarily due to lack of projects. Should I ask my manager for explanation? Is it time to find another job?

Tags: job-search, manager, layoff, covid-19

I was laid off temporarily (3 months) due to lack of projects in our department. However, what is concerning for me is that only 4 out of 45 people were laid off in our department and I was one of them.
The only official explanation I was given was that the layoffs are only due to reduction in work caused by the coronavirus pandemic.

But if there is less work, there is less work for everyone. It's not like a specific project was delayed or cancelled and we usually transfer from one project to another frequently. Just before being laid off, I was working on two different projects (though both of them were in their finishing stage).
What I want to ask my manager is on what basis was the decision made. Was it solely due to the lack of work, or was my performance also a factor. It is important to me, because if there are performance issues, then I need to know so that I can make an effort to improve them. Up until now I have not been told of any performance issues.

Do you think it is a good idea to talk to my manager and ask for an explanation? Or I should just take the clue and start looking for other jobs?

Comment: What's stopping you both talking to your manager and looking for another role?

Comment: What country are you in?

Comment: Does it really matter? You won't have a job in the next 3+ months if you don't start looking for a new one *right now*.

Comment: You should be able to largely figure out what to do if you answer a few questions for yourself: Would you be okay with being laid off for another 3 months after the current 3 months, and a few more months after that? Or just laid off permanently? What would stop that from happening? What can *you* do to stop that from happening? Does your manager care about your personal development? Does your manager expect you to just blindly follow instructions? Which type of manager do you want to work for?

Comment: Thanks for your comments. Yes i have started updating my resume to apply for jobs. I understand there is not necessarily less work for everyone, but its still concerning for me that i was among the 4 "buckets" to be eliminated. I am in a Nordic country and legislation over here is such that it is difficult to fire or layoff a permanent employees. But just recently some of these legislation were changed due to the corona virus which made it easier for the employers to layoff workers.

Comment: @aakalim: if the law in your country says that this can only be temporary, and that they have to take you back in 3 months, then maybe that will reassure you. Even so, if at the end of 3 months projects haven't picked up, and the temporary permission to lay off is over, so they need to make 10% redundancies, then they're pretty much going to pick the same people if they can. After they've been through whatever process the law stipulates for redundancies.

Comment: Also, other companies around the world have responded to this kind of 10% under-funding either by putting everyone on 90% part-time, or by giving everyone a 10% paycut without cutting hours. Maybe it's just because the law doesn't allow it in your country, but since they haven't spread the pain they have to accept that the pain is falling only on you (and 3 others), and so you're way more likely to leave.

Comment: @joeqwerty I think what he means is, the lack of work effects all employees equally, so why was he chosen. If the lack of work was due to a specific partner with whom only his team dealt with, it would make more sense.

Comment: Country might be important. "temporarily laid off" could mean from 0% to 70% (within the limit of 6157.68€ per month) of the salary depending on where you are from.

Comment: Whats your jurisdiction? Employment laws are vastly different and so is culture.

Comment: @aakalim is this programming related ?  software ????????

Comment: As everyone has said, this is a completely pointless discussion until the country is known.

Answer (score 130):

Update your resume and look for another job.

No matter the reason, you've been put in the bottom 10% of employees, and deemed to be expendable.

If it's not by department, not by project, or anything else you can point to, then the reason is you.  WHY the reason is you is irrelevant.  If you ask for an explanation, you will just get some managerial nonsense and HR friendly explanation.  Anything else, and your manager opens himself and the company  up to a lawsuit.  They won't do that, no matter how much they like you personally.

There is no guarantee that you'll be back after 3 months, either.

You are better off looking for another job, if for no other reasons than to cover your bases.  Don't turn down a good offer, even if your company calls you back.  They've demonstrated that they have no faith in you or loyalty towards you.  Respond in kind.

Comment: Couldn't agree more and wouldn't add an answer, as this is exactly what I would say. 100% get another job. In my career I have never seen this go well as you've described. Also agree the reason will never be revealed, and can be something trivial that doesn't reflect your work or character anyway. Good luck.

Comment: Whatever reason you were picked to be laid off, I don't suppose not working for 3 months helps with that? So your situation would only get worse because they realize your absence didn't affect anyone (as far as the manager is aware).

Comment: Depending on jurisdiction "bottom 10%" could just mean "shortest employment history" or "no children to support".

Comment: @I'mwithMonica: The *why* makes no difference. If you're expendable, you're expendable, and you should respond accordingly. This isn't about "trust" or "loyalty," this is a business decision, for both OP and OP's former employer.

Comment: @Kevin I think it does make a difference: A great employee might be the one to get laid off just because of those social criteria, but actually might be the one they would have wanted to keep. That employee would have a lot less problems getting hired somewhere else. It doesn't mean they are expendable (as in "we want to get rid of them").

Comment: @I'mwithMonica: If the company fired you, then *they consider you* expendable, by some criteria. It's not your problem if the company is using good criteria or bad criteria. Your problem is "Where will my next paycheck come from?"

Comment: Thank you for you answer. I will definitely start looking for new jobs now. This whole situation has now left me feeling undervalued and unappreciated by my company. The only problem is that finding a new job in this market situation would be difficult. So i may have to return to the same company after 3 months.

Comment: @aakalim as already said, even if you will return, you will still be on the "expendable" list, so you shouldn't stop looking.

Comment: @aakalim Also, you have to feed yourself and other responsabilities. Be it car, gas, bank loans, food, utilities, internet, clothes, hygiene products, house, pets, medicine ... It doesn't matter. You have to get money in, *somehow*. If you are on a layoff, you probably should be allowed to work somewhere outside the area you currently work in (e.g.: if you work in IT, you probably can work in a bar doing non-IT stuff). Always check what the law says.

Comment: @aakalim return if you have to, but do not stop looking.  Believe me, I know what it is like to feel undervalued.  That's a clear indication that you don't belong there.  Use that anger/disgust with them to motivate your efforts.  It's good to have that in your mind when you go into an interview, that you are worth it.  That translates to confidence and interviewers like that.

Comment: @I'mwithMonica The why doesn't matter, and the OP will never get an honest answer.  On paper, my friend was not let go because he had MS.  But, of course, that's why he was let go. Ever wonder why those company handbooks are so huge?  It's so that they have all sorts of rarely enforced rules and guidelines that every last employee will violate..  Those violations go ignored until they want to get rid of you.

Comment: _" So i may have to return to the same company after 3 months."_ Even if so, you will have lost nothing by looking around for another job meanwhile.

Comment: while i agree with this answer regarding what OP should do i'd counter the bottom 10% part.  I've had to lay off arguably "better" employees during slow times because they aren't currently billing against a client and upper management has strong reservations against removing people from client projects unless absolutely warranted

Comment: @USER_8675309 about 10% were laid off, he was in that 10%.  That sends the only message he needs to hear

Comment: @Old_Lamplighter that's a succinct way to put it.  I once had to let go of a very strong junior employee for the sole reason of they were not currently billing against a client.  We hired that person back about 4 months later, when we had much more work to be done.  it's why i give the ABB rule to anyone in the consulting industry that asks -- Always Be Billing

Comment: @USER_8675309 Well, the companies I've worked for always managed to FIND work for the ones they wanted to keep, even by reassigning them to different departments.  The lack of communication from the manager is what throws up the red flags to me.  Ever see an announcement "He has left the company to pursue other interests"?  This is the same kind of damning by saying nothing.,

Comment: I would add to "Update your resume" that you should spend time reviewing and polishing your skillsets, especially (at this time) interviewing and job hunting skills.  Re-energize these into your everyday work life (counterweight to complacency and stasis).  Read Martin Yate's book "Knock Em Dead".  Visit your anger and disgust but don't feed it, instead feed your curiosity, wonder, gratitude, and vision.  Talk to your boss or boss's boss as if interviewing - to audit your job performance, but also to show them how indispensable you are.  Do not burn "people" bridges, only 
"project" bridges.

Comment: @I'mwithMonica *"A great employee might be the one to get laid off just because of those social criteria, but actually might be the one they would have wanted to keep."* If you've been laid off, whether or not they *wanted* to keep you is irrelevant, because they *didn't* keep you. They had to get rid of someone, and they chose you. That's the only fact that matters. How they chose and how they felt about it don't really matter. Even if you go back, you now know you're the person they'll choose to get rid of first, because *they did*.

Comment: @anaximander exactly.  I've seen favors called in,, money drawn from different budgets, reassignments, et cet.  If they want you, they will keep you.  Unless, of course it's a union shop, and seniority is the only factor.

Comment: @Old_Lamplighter What is a "union shop"? That is a non-concept over here. - As my initial commont stated: This is based on jurisdiction! You are assuming some niche system, seemingly the one in the US, so I am assuming another one.

Comment: @I'mwithMonica I made no assumptions, I stated what is an exception to the rule.

Answer (score 30):

I agree with Old_Lamplighter that, justified or not, you have been categorized as the expendable bottom 10 percent and you should start looking for another job immediately.
However I think you have nothing to lose by asking your manager for some honest feedback. Sure, he/she might just give you "managerial nonsense" and a "HR friendly explanation". On the other hand, if you are lucky, he/she might give you some useful tips for improvement.

Comment: I'm a bit more utilitarian than you :D

Comment: @Old_Lamplighter Ah, but there's nothing to lose! Once a a new job has been secured, OP could go even further, asking the manager, "I've found a new job. Can you give me any advice?"

Comment: @employee-X I've seen ex bosses pursue former employees and try to ruin their new jobs.  So, I'm a bit more cynical.  This is a good answer though, and I don't assume I am 100% correct

Comment: @Old_Lamplighter Wouldn't that be a basis for a defamation lawsuit if they did that, though?

Comment: @EJoshuaS-ReinstateMonica Yes, but for defamation, you need to prove damages.  How do you prove damages?

Comment: @EJoshuaS-ReinstateMonica Also, how do you think your current employer would feel if you sued your ex employer over it?  Now your current employer knows you will sue employers.

Comment: @Old_Lamplighter That's a good point.

Answer (score 25):

It is entirely feasible you were let go because your projects were finishing up-- you can be left behind with no disruptions to other projects. That makes you expendable, almost regardless of performance.

Still, it is a good idea to talk to your manager. The worst that can happen, and the most likely, is that the manager will give you little to no information. Also ask what the likelihood of you coming back in three months is, how you can best use the remaining time to improve yourself, etc.-- anything else that would put you at ease. It can only help.

Comment: Good answer, and a good alternative perspective to mine.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I agree it is possible that i was let go because my projects were finishing up. In fact i would very much like to believe that! But the problem is i don't know for sure.

Comment: This is a likely explanation. Nonetheless, the OP should start looking for a new job, since even if he was chosen just by bad luck, there is no guarantee at all that in three months time there will be more projects and he will be recalled. Nothing personal, it is just business, but it works both ways.

Comment: I find it hard to believe that someone who was considered one of the top performers in the company would be the one on the chopping block just because the timing worked out that way.

Comment: @SJuan: yes of course. You're right.

Comment: @eps, yeah, he's probably not a top performer then, but think about it this way. Is it worth firing someone else, taking the time to get this guy up to speed, during which time you down a person on an ongoing project? Only for the best.

Answer (score 8):

At least in the UK we have government help for furlough, which applies up to a limit. Therefore it makes sense to furlough some employees rather than reducing the salaries of all - it's better to spend someone else's money than your own. All other things being equal, the employees to furlough are the ones with the highest salary below the cut-off, as that's the most benefit for the company's cash flow.

We also are aware of which employees were feeling more stressed about the pandemic or have caring responsibilities, and tended to furlough them rather than those who were better able to work from home. Also within my team we have certain specialisations so needed to keep some people with those specialisations. For example, the company's continuous integration guru left, so we brought back my team's developer in test to cover until we got a replacement, as he had CI experience.

So don't just assume being furloughed is only a matter of performance, there are numerous factors as to why particular individuals are or are not furloughed.

Answer (score 3):

There's definitely no reason for you to remain idle, "hoping" that they will call you back.  Dust off the ol' resume and get shopping for a new job.  Pronto.

Answer (score 1):

I was one of the first people to get laid off.  So I quickly found myself another job.  Subsequently, more people got laid off, and they had much more trouble finding work because the available jobs had been filled by people in the first wave of layoffs.

Consider yourself fortunate.  Get off your ass and start looking for work now, while the looking is good.

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can ask is how the company will manage without your particular skillset. Pethaps your skillset is expendable because they can do without by taxing others who possess a similar skills and are otherwise not easy to replace. There might be many reasons for letting you go that are not performance based but rather otherwise strategic.